# Azure Data Flow expression builder not able to add string

Tags: azure-data-factory

Error when connecting to Azure dataflow

I have given in Dataflow expression builder in sync

value of parameterdomain is coming from source column name

File Name Option: output to single file
File name : concat($parameterdomain,'.csv')

During Debug i get below error

```
Failure type  User configuration issue
```

Details
Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'sinksource'(Line 17/Col 12): Column operands are not allowed in literal expressions
Source   Pipeline

Comment: `value of parameterdomain is coming from source column name`, can you show how you are assigning source column name to the dataflow pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have checked the expression checkbox in the parameters tab of dataflow activity.

[image]